# Swapping multiple images using timer

Tags: javascript, image, timer

I am using JavaScript to change a background-image after a certain amount of time. But I have another 2 images I need to change in exactly the same timeframe. So images A1, B1, C1, then after 4 sec. images A2, B2, C2.

This is how I change one of the images (id="bg-image"), but how do I use the same function to make the other images (id="cta-image" and id="top-image") change too?

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
<script>        
        var i = 0;
setInterval(function($) {
  var a = ["bg2.jpg", "bg3.jpg", "bg.jpg"];
  i = (i > (a.length - 1)) ? 0 : i;
  document.getElementById('bg-image').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + a[i++] + "')";
}, 4000, $);
</script>
```

```css
.bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: url("bg.jpg") no-repeat bottom center / 100%;
  background-size: auto 100%;
}

.top {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: url("top.png") no-repeat top center / 100%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.cta {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    background: url("cta.png") no-repeat bottom center / 100%;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: hidden; position: absolute; left: 0px; top:0px; height: 100%; width: 100%; cursor:pointer; background-color: #3165ce;">
  <div id="bg-image" class="bg"></div>
  <div id="cta-image" class="cta"></div>
  <div id="top-image" class="top"></div>
</div>
```

I tried to copy the function which did not work.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/253693/discussion-on-question-by-roarky-swapping-multiple-images-using-timer); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for helping me through this, CBroe:

```
<script>
    var i = 0;
    setInterval(function($){ 
        var a = ["bg.jpg", "bg2.jpg", "bg3.jpg"];
        var b = ["cta.png", "cta2.png", "cta3.png"]; 
        var c = ["top.png", "top2.png", "top3.png"];
        i = i + 1;
        i = (i > (a.length - 1))?0:i;
        document.getElementById('bg-image').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + a[i] + "')";
        document.getElementById('cta-image').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + b[i] + "')";
        document.getElementById('top-image').style.backgroundImage = "url('" + c[i] + "')";
    }, 4000,$);

</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).